# Is there a method which convert elements in String to BigInt?

Tags: scala

This code :

```
1234.toString.map(_.asDigit)
```

returns :

```
scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

but I need a `scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[BigInt]`

There does not seem to be a method such as asBigInt which will convert the String characters to BigInt . How can this be done ?

Comment: Have you tried to write it youtrself? I don't think there is predefined method for this

Comment: @Tala I haven't tried to write this myself, asking the question in case I don't need to :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
1234.toString.map(_.asDigit).map(BigInt(_))
```

Answer (score 6):

There is an implicit conversion  `implicit def int2bigInt(i: Int): BigInt` from int to BigInt in the [companion object BigInt](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.BigInt%24) you can use here:

```
scala> 1234.toString.map(_.asDigit : BigInt)
res34: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[BigInt] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4)
```